# draft_to_pending action doesn’t seem to fire

Tags: save-post

I have the action ‘draft_to_pending‘ set to fire on a custom post type. I assume that when the user clicks “Status » Edit” changes it to “Pending” and then clicks “Save Pending”, this action is suppose to fire, but it doesn’t seem to do so.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('draft_to_pending','notify_email_rejected',99);

function notify_email_rejected($post){

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $is_rejected = get_post_meta($post_id,'rejected_listing',true);

    $owner_id = get_post_meta($post_id,'owner',true);
    $owner = get_userdata($owner_id);

    $to = $owner->user_email;

    $headers = "From: HayForSale <admin@hayforsale.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = 'Your listing was rejected at HayForSale.com';

    $rejection = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rejection_message', true );

    $message = 'some html';

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might not have all the right actions covered, try to add those:

```
add_action('new_to_pending', 'notify_email_rejected');
add_action('auto-draft_to_pending', 'notify_email_rejected');
```